# Change right click event of tkinter command

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-menu

I want to detect the right click event on tkinter Menu command.
Consider code below.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

menu_button = ttk.Menubutton(root, text="MENU")
menu_button.grid()

m = tk.Menu(menu_button, tearoff=False, activeborderwidth=0)
menu_button["menu"] = m # To avoid garbage collection

m.add_command(label="an option", command=lambda: print("option1"))
m.add_command(label="another option", command=lambda: print("option2"))

root.mainloop()
```

When I click `an option` or `another option`, the commands are called as expected. But want I want to do is catch right click event. Can anyone knows that how can I detect it?

Comment: You mean, when you right click the menu, a command is run?

Comment: If it helps, you can do this `menu_button.bind('<Button-3>', lambda e: print("option0"))`

Answer (score 0):

use `button.bind("<Button-3>", event)`. Consider this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text='right click this')
button.pack()

button.bind("<Button-3>", lambda e: print('You right clicked'))

root.mainloop()
```